# cyanogenmod 13 freezes and restarts

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I have installed Cyanogenmode 13 in my Asus zenfone 5, it works perfectly for few days then started giving the following issue:

**It freezes and reboot**

I have noticed it happened randomly, sometimes while playing game, chatting, opening contact, browsing

Any suggestion.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please use other sites, such as https://android.stackexchange.com, for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: possibly you did not install the rom correctly

Comment: It is not the right for such question. Ask this [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/).